# Dedicated DSP for delayed replay

Tags: delay

I'm looking for a dedicated DSP chip that will allow sampling and delayed replay of a signal, given the following parameters:

- buffer should be integrated
- configuration of the DSP chip (if needed) should be possible via host CPU (SPI or serial)
- starting and stopping the sampling/replay should be possible via a dedicated pin
- reading the samples via the host CPU is NOT required!
- sampling should be done with a frequency of at least 2MHz (since a temporal resolution of 1 µs is required)
- since this is for replaying a digital signal, a low resolution (even 1 bit per sample) is possible
- buffering should allow for 250 ms period

I did not find any stand-alone DSP with this characteristics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to believe, that you actually looked. You probably don't even need a DSP for that, a normal microcontroller should be sufficient.

For example, the STM32F4-Discovery board comes with an ARM Cortex-M3 that has several ADC channels that can do 2.4MSps each and up to 7.2MSps in interleaved mode. There's a DAC for signal output as well. But since your signal is digital anyways, you can probably sample with just a normal digital input pin. If 1bit per sample is enough, 250ms of a 2MHz sampled signal require 62500bytes which fits into the memory of the ARM quite well.

Comment: The reason I wanted to avoid using a dedicated microcontroller is that I wanted something with a very low pin count, since this will be used in addition to an existing host CPU.

Comment: Why don't you do it on the host CPU? You may be able to clock it in via the SPI interface. If the CPU has a bus, you could also clock the data in and out with a simple internal shift register. Most DSP are NOT low pin count

Answer (score 2):

I also suggest a general purpose microcontroller.

Your problem involves no processing and your data appears to be digital - so you don't even need an onboard ADC and DAC. The only thing you need is RAM and some very lightweight logic.

It would be silly to record digital data bit by bit - you only need to record the number of clock ticks between transitions. So if your input signal changes not so frequently, 250ms of binary data at 2 MHz might fit in just a few kilobytes.

The STM32F405RGT6 has 64 pins only; only needs a quartz and passives; and has 192kbytes of internal memory (786ms at 2MHz, 1-bit, using naive encoding). Fast enough for sampling with a timer, by using input pin change interrupts, or by clocking it as a SPI slave.